# Failed to resolve: common Android Studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am recently getting this error message on gradle build/sync:

[Image of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmttX.png)

When I click on "open file", it switches to the **build.gradle (App)** window.

I am not getting any solution for this on stackoverflow. Please check the code and let me know the issue.

I would really appreciate your help.

**build.gradle (Project)**

```html
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {

            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        google()
    }


    dependencies {

        /*compile('javax.inject:javax.inject:1',
                'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7',
                'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1',
                'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0',
                'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1')

        compile files('libs/publisher-sdk-android-5.1.0.jar')*/

    }
}
```

**build.gradle (App)**

```html
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        //multiDexEnabled = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    /*lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }*/


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    // Vungle SDK
    //implementation 'com.github.vungle:vungle-android-sdk:6.2.5'
    // Optional Google Play Services - Location and Basement
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'

    //Replace it with Google Analytics?
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.10'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1' has some problems. upgrade it to 4.0.1 and check.

Comment: Google Services seems to have some problems everytime. Anyhow, I've checked it, but still having the error, however thank you very much for our effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use these

Check first

Go to Settings/Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment option > Instant Run and uncheck all the three boxes.

**1**. Upgrading Gradle services URL:

Project > Gradle > Wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties

Change URL from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
```

(Find latest distributionUrl gradle plugin version Here: http://services.gradle.org/distributions

**Make sure to use gradle-x.xx-all.zip )

**2**. Delete your build folder

When you run project, build folder will be created automatically

**3**. Go to BUILD option in menu > Clean the project, Build the project

It should work without instant run.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help! This didn't solve the problem directly, I had to to add maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } as well, as there had been some problem with "common.jar" that couldn't be found, but as your tip brought me to this and to download the latest gradle, and solving some other problem with accepting the latest gradle, I will mark this as the solution! Thanks again ;)